# HereMap: Shift map while hovering on location

Tags: jquery, maps, here-api, here-maps-rest

My HTML page design like this

Right side Here Map and left side more than 25 locations. as soon as page loads, all 25 locations are plotted on map and when window scroll, Marker on map got big for the location which is on window viewport.

everything works good if all the locations are in same city, state or country. But if locations are from across country. then map got small to show all the locations.

What i wanted is that Map should not get small, instead it should deploy all the locations but should show first location on map. **And when we scroll and next location will come up, Map should move to that marker.**

My code for the location plotting

```
function loadHeremap(element){
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
        'apikey': 'MyAPIKEY',
        useHTTPS: true
    });
    var pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers({
      tileSize: pixelRatio === 1 ? 256 : 512,
      ppi: pixelRatio === 1 ? undefined : 320
    });
    
    var city_latitude = $('#latitude').text();
    var city_longitude = $('#longitude').text();
    
    var map = new H.Map(document.getElementById(element),
      defaultLayers.normal.map,{
      center: {lat: city_latitude, lng: city_longitude},
      zoom: 7,
      pixelRatio:pixelRatio
    });
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', function () { map.getViewPort().resize();});
      
    var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));
    var behavior    = behavior.disable(H.mapevents.Behavior.WHEELZOOM);

    var ui = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);
    
    var mapSettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
    mapSettings.setVisibility(false);
    var zoom = ui.getControl('zoom');   
    zoom.setAlignment('right-bottom');  
    
    allMarkers = [];    
    var event_latlon_map = $('.coll_event_data').text();        
    event_latlon_map=JSON.parse(event_latlon_map);
    var locations = event_latlon_map;
    
    var group = new H.map.Group();
    var marker, i;
    var icon  = new H.map.Icon('../images/dark_blue_circle.png');
    var BigIcon = new H.map.Icon('../images/dark_blue_large.png');
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        group.addEventListener('pointerdown', function (evt) {
            var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
                content: evt.target.getData()
            });
            
            var position = evt.target.getGeometry(),
                data = evt.target.getData(),
                bubbleContent = evt.target.getData(),
                bubble = onMarkerClick.bubble;
              
            if (!bubble) {
                bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(position, {
                    content: bubbleContent
                });  
                ui.addBubble(bubble);
                onMarkerClick.bubble = bubble;
            } else {
                bubble.setPosition(position);
                bubble.setContent(bubbleContent);
                bubble.open();
            }
            checkInfoBubble(bubble,map);
        }, false);
        group.addEventListener('pointermove', function (evt) {
            var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getGeometry(), {
            // read custom data
            content: evt.target.getData()
        });
        var bubble_state=bubble.getState();
        var position = evt.target.getGeometry(),
            data = evt.target.getData(),
            bubbleContent = evt.target.getData(),
            bubble = onMarkerClick.bubble;
          
            if (!bubble) {
                bubble = new H.ui.InfoBubble(position, {
                    content: bubbleContent
                });
                ui.addBubble(bubble);
                onMarkerClick.bubble = bubble;
            } else {
                bubble.setPosition(position);
                bubble.setContent(bubbleContent);
                bubble.open();
            }
            checkInfoBubble(bubble,map);
        }, false);
        
        var loc_event_id    = locations[i][3];
        var loc_event_name  = locations[i][0];
        var loc_venue_name  = locations[i][4];
        var loc_event_url         = locations[i][7];
        
        var full_detail = '<div data-id="'+id+'" class="detail"><a href="'+url+'"><div class="marker">'+name+'</div></a><div class="label">Venue: </div><div class="name">'+name1+'</div></div>';

        // Add the first marker
        if(i==0){
            marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},{icon: BigIcon });
        }else{
            marker = new H.map.Marker({lat:locations[i][1], lng:locations[i][2]},{icon: icon });
        }
        marker.setData(full_detail);
        group.addObject(marker);
        allMarkers.push(marker);
        map.addObject(group);     
    }
    //map.getViewPort().setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
    //map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());
    map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
            position: {lat:first_lat,lng:first_lon},
            zoom:3
    });
}
```

Code when location is into the viewport and marker gets big.

```
function hover_on_heremap(id){
    var icon2 = new H.map.Icon('../images/large_icon.png');
    for ( var i = 0; i< allMarkers.length; i++){
        var htmlString=allMarkers[i].P;
        if(htmlString){
            var maker_id_array = htmlString.match(/data-id=\"([0-9]+)\"/);
            var single_id=maker_id_array[1];
            if (id == single_id){
                allMarkers[i].setIcon(icon2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this code do change the small icon into big one when hover on locations but didn't shift the map.

Answer (score 1):

Your map gets "small" because you are using `map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds())` to set the camera to a bounding box of all your map markers. In other words, you are asking the camera to zoom out far enough so that all markers are visible in the viewport.

You can use `map.getViewModel().setLookAtData()` to focus the camera on a specific location, such as the geocoordinates of a given marker. You can also set a fixed zoom level. The following blog post has more information on how to use the camera:

https://developer.here.com/blog/now-in-3d-learn-how-to-use-the-camera-in-the-new-javascript-api-3.1

Comment: I am changing my code as per your suggestions but now i am getting error `TypeError: group.getBoundingBox is not a function`.

Comment: and is it possible to plot all the location but focus on one camera?

Comment: You need to use setLookAtData() and pass it a single GeoCoordinate, not a bounding box, e.g. something like this: 

`map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({position: {lat: 52.5544, lng: 13.29036}, zoom: 18.1});`

Comment: copy paste the above example and now i am getting `TypeError: map.getViewModel(...).setLookAtData is not a function`

Comment: Are you using 3.0 or 3.1 of the JS API?

Comment: we are using 3.0. we used 3.1 but it wasn't compatible with all the browser so we switched back to 3.0.

Comment: In that case, just use the map.setCenter() method to focus on one specific marker.

Comment: Thanks for the help. it's helping. please let me know how do i shift the map position to the next marker?

Comment: I am still waiting for an answer which can shift the map. Please let me know if that is possible.

Comment: As leopectus mentioned, for API v3.0 you should use `map.setCenter({lat: xx, lng: xx})`. If you want smooth animation, then add true as a second parameter of setCenter method: `map.setCenter({lat: xx, lng: xx}, true)`